# Android RDP Client locks screen

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, android

I use Microsoft RDP Client on Android to connect my computer. But screen locks when I connect.

I couldn't find an option about this.

How can I use both at same time.

Comment: Which screen locks? The Android device or the PC?

Comment: PC screen locks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like the normal behaviour I would expect from an RDP client. You might want to look at a VNC client/server instead. Or you might be able to use teamviewer.

In either case, google is your friend to find the right client/server applications for you.